# Runtime HTML not working with knockoutJS?

Tags: knockout.js, sammy.js

I am new to SammyJS. I am trying to create a sample app usig SammyJS and KnockoutJS. I am creating some RunTime HTML and adding binding attributes, But knockout binding not working with that.

```
var priorities = { Low: 0, Important: 1, Medium: 2, High: 3, VeryHigh: 4 };
var mailBoxViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;
    self.heading = 'Learn Sammy JS';
    self.Messages = ko.observableArray([{ Id: 1, Message: 'Hello', Description: '', Sender: { Name: 'Ravi', SentOn: new Date(), Priority: priorities.Low} }, { Id: 2, Message: 'Meeting', Description: '', Sender: { Name: 'Chandar', SentOn: new Date(), Priority: priorities.High}}]);
    var routes = $.sammy(function () {
        this.element_selector = '#content';
        this.before(function () {
            this.swap('');
        });
        this.get("#/Messages", function (context) {
            var div = $("<div class='well'></div>");
            div.append("<h1 data-bind='text:heading'></h1>");
            var table = $("<table class='table' ></table>");
            table.append("<thead><tr><th>Messages</th></tr></thead>");
            table.append("<tbody data-bind='foreach: Messages'><tr><td data-bind='text:Message'></td></tr></tbody>");
            div.append(table);
            context.$element().append(div);
        });
        this.get("#/Sent", function (context) {
            var div = $("<div class='well'></div>");
            var table = $("<table class='table'></table>");
            table.append("<thead><tr><th>Messages</th></tr></thead>");
            table.append("<tbody><tr><td>Hello World</td></tr></tbody>");
            div.append(table);
            context.$element().append(div);
        });
    });
    $(function () {
        routes.run("#/Messages");
    });
};
ko.applyBindings(new mailBoxViewModel());
```

Comment: `ko.applyBindings(new mailBoxViewModel());` is called before sammy has added the HTML to the page

Comment: So what should we need to do here ?

Comment: Do you get an error ? What exactly is not working ?

Comment: Sorry missed that you did routes.run that should make the code run synchronized. But it's a bit volotile to assume that Sammy will run synchronized

Comment: the binding is not working `this.get("#/Messages", function (context) {}` method i am creating some HTML and data-binding. I am not getting any error from that code.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem (as Anders was hinting at) is that Knockout can only create data bindings for elements that are already in your DOM at the time that `ko.applyBindings` is executed. It doesn't know anything about elements that you subsequently add to your DOM using jQuery and so ignores any `data-bind` attributes on them.

You're trying to dynamically generate DOM sections based on your routes. In order for that to work with Knockout, you'll need to call `ko.applyBindings` again each time you generate a new section. However, that's not really the usual philosophy for working with Knockout, since the whole point of using a data-binding system like it is to avoid manually generating and manipulating DOM elements in views. What most people would do is create templates for everything at the very beginning and then let their route code tell the ViewModel which template to use based on the route (i.e. you'd use an observable as the name for your template binding and your route code would set that observable to the name of the appropriate template).

Comment: Can you suggest me an example of using templates with sammyJS ?

Comment: Take a look at the Knockout documentation for the `template` binding, paying particular attention to Note 5, "Dynamically choosing which template is used". You'd avoid using Sammy's `swap()` and instead of generating elements, your route code would just set the observable holding the appropriate template's name.

Comment: I added a answer, it uses my library. It removes the need to specify templates and by convention uses the ViewModel type as template name

Answer (score 0):

I add a answer here even if ebohlman answer is accepted, I have made a little bootstrapper for KO that uses Sammy. It has a bit smaller footprint than Durandal and might fit your case.

Check out the demo project here

https://github.com/AndersMalmgren/Knockout.Bootstrap.Demo